# Creating a stored procedure if it does not already exist, but do not alter and do not drop the existing one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have found examples where a stored procedure is dropped or altered in case if it exists.

But how do I write a T-SQL batch script that does strictly the following:

- checks if the stored procedure exists:

  - if it exists, the script does nothing at all - I do not want to drop and rewrite or alter the existing procedure because it might have changes made by someone else. Also, the script should not abort with an error because it might be a part of a larger batch of changes.
  - if it doesn't exist, only then create a new procedure with my code

?

Comment: Is getting an error good enough? because if you run a `create procedure` statement and that procedure already exist, than SQL Server will raise an error 'There is already an object named 'Your procedure name' in the database.'...

Comment: You raise a good point there @ZoharPeled .

Comment: Does it need to be atomic? If so, and if only your code will be playing in the sandbox for this SP, you may want to use an [application lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to protect the operation against multiple invocations.

Comment: _it might have changes made by someone else_ You need a source control system so changes / versions are never lost. And a change management process that does not allow random, undocumented, unreviewed, and untested changes to code.

Comment: @SMor  You are right. Unfortunately, sometimes life is crude and a database might be maintained by two different teams throwing random SQL scripts at each other.

Answer (score 3):

When creating a Stored Procedure, it can be the only statement in the batch. This means that something like the below will fail:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas s JOIN sys.procedures p ON s.schema_id = p.schema_id WHERE s.[name] = N'dbo' AND p.[name] = N'YourProcedure') BEGIN

    CREATE PROC dbo.YourProcedure @TableName sysname AS
    BEGIN

        SELECT *
        FROM sys.tables t
        WHERE t.name = @TableName;

    END;
END;
```

Therefore, if you want to check if the procedure exists first, and then create it if not, you have to use "dynamic" SQL (it's not really dynamic, as there's nothing dynamic in it):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas s JOIN sys.procedures p ON s.schema_id = p.schema_id WHERE s.[name] = N'dbo' AND p.[name] = N'YourProcedure') BEGIN

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'CREATE PROC dbo.YourProcedure @TableName sysname AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM sys.tables t
    WHERE t.name = @TableName;

END;';
END;
```

This means that you will need to escape any single quotes in the Stored Procedure's definition when pasting it into the dynamic statement.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess I'll have to go with this ugly stringified solution. Microsoft sometimes can be so weird in their decisions.